# cannot use raw_input if monkeyrunner is included in python script

Tags: python, monkeyrunner

I want to input some values in my python script.
Part of my code is:

```
import os,sys,subprocess,shlex,time
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner
import  com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyDevice
from com.android.monkeyrunner.recorder import MonkeyRecorder as recorder
user = raw_input("enter your username")
print user
```

When i am executing the code as "monkeyrunner camautoopen.py"
Then i can only input username. But i cannot print it.

when my code is :

```
import os,sys,subprocess,shlex,time
user = raw_input("enter your username")
print user
```

and i execute the script as python camautoopen.py , then i get the desired result.

Comment: I want username to be entered for the script and i dint want to enter username for device

Comment: there might be some file created which logs your stdout, or maybe some option in monkeyrunner

Comment: if you really want to print `user`, why don't you open a file and print to it?

Comment: its not that i want to print user...that is just one case...i cannot execute any statement written below raw_input

Comment: other case i cannot sort dictionary  import collections  dict = {'2014-09-16': 'bseid_580129', '2014-09-18': 'bseid_583368', '2014-09-17': 'bseid_582500', '2014-09-23': 'bseid_564429', '2014-09-14': 'bseid_557089', '2014-09-15': 'bseid_579516', '2014-09-20': 'bseid_585476', '2014-09-24': 'bseid_565169', '2014-09-21': 'bseid_561715', '2014-09-22': 'bseid_563074', '2014-09-13': 'bseid_578927', '2014-09-19': 'bseid_560756'}
dict=collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items()))
print dict.items()[0][1]                                     i can do this in python (without monkey runner) but not with it

Comment: You may try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which is 100% python.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Mac OS X? I had the same problem, and I found the fix here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56318

I basically needed to swap out Jython with a newer version. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can either include the libraries of monkey and write the script by your own in java

```
import eu.fbk.se.androidmonkey.Monkey;

import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.view.Display;

public class MonkeyLoginActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {

private int NUM_EVENTS = 320;
public MonkeyLoginActivityTest() {
    super(LoginActivity.class);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
     @Override
     protected void setUp() throws Exception {
             super.setUp();
             setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

     }

     public void testMonkeyEvent() {
             Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
             Instrumentation inst = getInstrumentation();
             PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();

             Monkey monkey = new Monkey(display,"com.wisemoo.tickleboards.dev.activities", inst, pm);



             // Generate and fire a random event. 
             for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EVENTS; i++) {
                 monkey.nextRandomEvent();
             }

     }

     @Override
     protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
             super.tearDown();
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but it will help other monkey runner `raw_input()` `input()` all were hanging for me too, i ended up make a http server to talk to monkey as described in this thread:

[Android Monkey Runner Device Calls Hang but Work when Process Is Killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395661/android-monkey-runner-device-calls-hang-but-work-when-process-is-killed)