# How can I pause Monkeyrunner for user input?

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner

If I am running in monkeyrunner and want the user to be able to input something into my python script while my program is running how can I do that?

Currently `input()` never registers that I hit enter.

I don't know why this is. I have searched yesterday and today, and found no answer.
I run my code by typing: `monkeyrunner.bat absolutePathnameToPythonFile`
 
I run the code from the command line on Windows 10. 
Monkeyrunner is using python version 2.5.3

Here is my Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

import sys

print("using python version: " + str(sys.version_info))

print("Enter anything to end program...")

character = input()
print(str(character)) #Never Gets here.

print("-Program Ended-")
```

Comment: Your program hangs at `input()`? Have you tried using `raw_input()` instead?

Comment: I get an error: Unresolved reference 'raw_input'

Comment: I found a simmilar question, but none of it's answers worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032674/cannot-use-raw-input-if-monkeyrunner-is-included-in-python-script

Comment: If you remove the line `from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice` does the problem persist?

Comment: I never did get an answer, but I no longer need one I suppose.

Comment: Fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26316730/3736955

Answer (score 0):

You can try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which is a drop-in replacement for `monkeyrunner` in 99% of the cases and because it's python you won't have to deal with those jython problems.

Comment: i've used AndroidViewClient/culebra and its much slower compared to monkeyrunner, its not sutable for automating realtime game under the hood its just using *adb input*

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but it will help other monkey runner `raw_input()` `input()` all were hanging for me too, i ended up make a http server to talk to monkey as described in this thread:

[Android Monkey Runner Device Calls Hang but Work when Process Is Killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395661/android-monkey-runner-device-calls-hang-but-work-when-process-is-killed)

I tried: `AndroidViewClient/culebra` but it was too slow