# Read from stdin with monkeyrunner

Tags: input, monkeyrunner, android-sdk-2.3

How do I read from stdin with monkeyrunner? I tried the following code.

```
import sys
print("type something")
something = sys.stdin.readline()
print(something)
```

I also tried the following:

```
print("type something")
something = raw_input()
print(something)
```

In both cases the program prints "type something" but it does not respond after I type something. It seems i am making some silly mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56318) with Jython 2.5.3, the version that is included with MonkeyRunner. The issue says Mac OS X but I am able to reproduce on Ubuntu.

To fix it, you can download the Jython 2.5.4rc1 standalone Jar from [the Jython website](https://www.jython.org/download.html) ([download link](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/python/jython-standalone/2.5.4-rc1/jython-standalone-2.5.4-rc1.jar)) and copy it into the `$SDK/tools/lib` directory. Note that the Jython 2.7.0 standalone Jar will not work properly. You don't need to rename the new Jar, but you do need to (re)move the old `jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar` from the directory.

Another option (if you only need user input) is to use [the input function](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyRunner.html#input) in the MonkeyRunner class.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me on Windows, but I was able to instead use HTTP for communicating: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64634081/771768